# HOWTO: Identify database connection string

Tags: java, android, database

Basically I want to develop a Android app for a forum, but I have no information about the back-end database, however I am registered with this forum and I have valid user name and password. Is there anyway by which I could identify the back-end database so I can directly connect to the database and fetch posts there?

Comment: That would be a security risk.

Comment: Your username/password for the forum won't give you access to the database even if you knew the connection string. You would also need the database credentials.

Comment: Ok then I will try and find out about the database from the admin.

Answer (score 2):

If the forum does not have any heavy security bugs, NO.

Answer (score 0):

You have to scrape data from the web page of the forum. Try Yahoo [Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/).